# button скачивание файла (js,jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, файлы, button

Каким образом можно заставить кнопку дать клиенту файл(локальный) через js

Потому что я не могу использовать `<a href="...">`-> сервер выдает ошибку `404`

Comment: английский понимаете? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery но даже там нужно задавать верный url, так что с 404 ошибкой все же разобраться придется наверное

Comment: `404` потому что файла по такому пути нет.... но всегда можно написать `<a href="/path/to/your/file.ext">файл</a>` и будет всё скачиваться ..пример: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrEzPy

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/html/a/download

Comment: и еще вам может пригодится такой кусок кода: `data=new Blob(["\ufeff",[data]],{type:' _myme type_'});
     var file=window.URL.createObjectURL(data);` после чего содержимое `file` можно подставлять как href в ссылку на созданный файл, добавляете туда атрибут из предыдущего коментария, и вуаля - файл можно сделать прямо в браузере на js и отдать на скачивание с помощью html.

Comment: нужно клиенту скачивать из сервера apk-файл

Comment: @МиколаКікець Значит пути проверяй. напортачил с ними значит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

404 означает,что по данной ссылке ничего нет,попробуйте проверить правильность адреса,как по мне через js это уже изобретать велосипед

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял речь идет о *локальном* файле на компьютере с браузером.
Исторически для этого использовался file:// протокол, но если страница открыта с сервера (по http), то по безопасности не даст сделать такой переход.

код

```
<a href="" onclick="location.href='file:///d:\\t.txt'; return false;">test</a>
```

работает например в хроме, если сам файл, его содержащий, размещен также локально. для инета надо играться с уровнем безопасности для сайта и в разных браузерах может оказаться разный подход к интерпретации. но без настроек безопасности точно работать не будет. а значит для "публичного" варианта не подойдет.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете уточнить некоторые нюансы, где находится страница которые вы открыли? она на сервере или у вас локально, т.к вы говорите отдать клиенту - значит сайт на сервере , а вы пытаетесь отдать файл который находится у вас локально . никак не связанный с сервером.  Собственно поэтому и отдает 404 ошибку

Возможно я не правильно понял ваше описание ?